# How to get a result from Google Places and pass it to the render method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

Feel like I'm missing something here on how callbacks / async code is working.
`places` is undefined.

```js
module.exports = (app) => {
    
    app.get('/searchresults', (req, res) => {
        var places = getGooglePlaces();
        res.render('searchresults', {places: places});
    });
};

function getGooglePlaces(){
    
    var gp = require('googleplaces');
    var config = require("../config.js");
    var googlePlaces = new gp(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);
    var parameters = {
        query: "restaurants in la"
    };
    var places = googlePlaces.textSearch(parameters, function (error, response) {
        return(response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise` to be able to get a result from a callback:

```
function getGooglePlaces(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
      var gp = require('googleplaces');
      var config = require("../config.js");
      var googlePlaces = new gp(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);
      var parameters = {
          query: "restaurants in la"
      };
      var places = googlePlaces.textSearch(parameters, function (error, response) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
          resolve(response);
      });
   });
};
```

Then use `then/catch` to get a result:

```
app.get('/searchresults', (req, res) => {
        getGooglePlaces()
          .then(places => res.render('searchresults', {places: places}))
          .catch(err => res.status(500).send('Error occured while searching Google Places');
    });
```